# JSON Parsing error -Invalid Character at position 0

Tags: c#, json, windows-runtime

I am trying to parse do a GET with my click method

```
Using Windows.Data.Json;

private async void getJSON_click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)

{ 
   var client=new HttpClient();
   client.MaxResponseBufferSize=1024*1024;
   var response= await Client.GetAsync(new Uri(The URL here));
   var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

   var component=JsonArray.Parse(result);

}
```

The Following is error message -
WINRT information :Invalid Character at position 0. Invalid JSON String.

This my JSON Data which i am trying to parse:
{"X-YZ-12345/AB.CD" :{"PM1":"F","PM2":"47.12"}}

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: What encoding type are you sending in? Are you sure you aren't getting a BOM character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not an array it an object. try `JsonObject`.

```
string result = @"{""X-YZ-12345/AB.CD"" :{""PM1"":""F"",""PM2"":""47.12""}}";
var jobj = JsonObject.Parse(result);
```